# High standard of service vs high standard service

Tags: phrase-usage

I recently read the following sentence:

"we are disappointed that we couldn’t give our customers the high standard service they expect"

Should this say high standard **of** service? It sounds odd without the **of** in the phrase.

Comment: You are right..it does sound odd. It should be 'High standards of service'.

Comment: Yes, it needs 'of' - or a hyphen: *high-standard service*.

Answer (score 0):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/search?f_0=Definition&pageSize=20&q_0=high%20standard%20of&scope=SENSE&type=dictionarysearch) list these usages of **a high standard of** x:

> ... a high standard of purity ...

and

> ... a high standard of fineness ...

and

> ... a high standard of morality ...